# Is there a way to check if a parameter is in stored procedure?

Tags: c#, asp.net, stored-procedures

I'm writing a general purpose function for feeding query string straight into a sproc. The algorithm is fairly basic - loop through query keys, use them as parameter names while the value are used as parameter values. So it looks like something like this:

```
ArrayList pars = new ArrayList();
SqlParameter p;
int tryInt;
for (int i = 0; i < req.QueryString.Count; i++) 
{
    key = req.QueryString.AllKeys[i];

    if (int.TryParse(req[key], out tryInt)) 
    {
        p = new SqlParameter("@" + key, SqlDbType.Int);
        p.Value = tryInt;
        pars.Add(p);
    }
}
```

This works fine so far, except that of course all query keys must match the parameters for the sproc, if they don't I get an SQL exception saying something like

```
@someParameter is not a parameter for procedure some_sproc
```

But I need to be able to pass in variables in the query string that won't be passed into the sproc, so I need a way to "ignore" them.

Is there a way to test whether a given stored procedure expects a certain parameter? So that I can do something along these lines

```
if (paramExists("@" + key, "some_sproc") && int.TryParse(req[key], out tryInt)) 
{
    p = new SqlParameter("@" + key, SqlDbType.Int);
    p.Value = tryInt;
    pars.Add(p);
}
```

Comment: While I got the answer I needed, I realized I didn't want to make another DB call. Instead what I now do is, any query variable that I want to pass as a parameter to a sproc I name with @ symbol at the start. So for example query like this file.aspx?sproc=somesproc&@par1=param1&par2=param2 will pass @par1 to sproc but not par2

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can interrogate the ANSI information_schema.parameters view, it returns all parameters with their position

```
SELECT parameter_name, ordinal_position FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.parameters
WHERE SPECIFIC_NAME = 'some_sproc'
```

Comment: Thanks. That works, though I wasn't crazy about the idea of making another DB call just for that so after thinking about it a bit I came up with an alternative solution. I've added a comment to my post with the details.

Answer (score 5):

You can use SqlCommandBuilder to get SP parameters:

```
using (SqlConnection sqlConn = new SqlConnection(yourConnStr))
using (SqlCommand sqlCmd = new SqlCommand(yourProcedureName, sqlConn))
{
    sqlConn.Open();
    sqlCmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
    SqlCommandBuilder.DeriveParameters(sqlCmd);
    // now you can check parameters in sqlCmd.Parameters
}
```

More details [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommandbuilder.aspx)

Comment: When you say *now you can check parameters* what do you mean by that? How do I go about doing that?

Comment: @TotZam for (int i = 0; i < sqlCmd.Parameters.Count; i++) sqlCmd.Parameters[i].ParameterName;

Answer (score 0):

Most DBs store "metadata" such as the structure of stored procedures in accessible system tables/views. If you're using MSS, I would look at sys.procedures and sys.parameters; join these two views and filter by procedure name.